# Cannot host the website at server - exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, web-applications, webforms

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms project (actually it's a project done by someone else and was given to me to fix some errors). My website loads properly on localhost, but when I replace the current version at the server with the pre-compiled version of the modified code, the website does not load and gives the following error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

I am new to ASP.NET and most of the solutions I found regarding this error are kind of complex. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Clean the solution & rebuild every project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace not only code: you have to replace the whole project. As it is web-forms PROJECT, it compiles all code, references, dependencies together, so you have to replace the whole project with a new one. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain this a little bit? How do I replace references and dependencies?

Comment: You don't need to look for some references and dependencies. Just change the code as you need, compile it in your computer, make sure that it works exactly as you need, and then just replace full project, not only some part. You may even delete application from IIS and create it again, if you are not sure about simple replacing. And remember: you don't need to have some additional files. You have to have only that files, that you have in your project.